# PHP: Put frequently encountered simple actions in a methods

Tags: php, design-patterns

I've been reading a lot about writing "high quality" PHP scripts and many people mentioned that it is a good practice to put the frequently encountered simple actions in a methods, such as multiply etc.

**[Example]**

```
<?php
class Test
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $result = 0;

        for ( $i = 0; $i < 10; $i++ )
        {
            $result += $this->multiply($result, $i);
        }

        return $result;
    }

    private function multiply($a, $b)
    {
        return $a * $b;
    }
}
```

**[Question]**

Does it worth it to create new methods for such simple functions like multiply, division and so on. Isn't it better to do just

```
$result += $result * $i;
```

instead of creating new methods. Are these methods really a good practice and are they slowing the performance even if it's by a microsecond.

**EDIT:**

**[Question 2]**
Randomly found out this code: http://pastebin.com/XjmcfHsK, do you think that the multiply method is not needed?

Comment: it's utterly pointless to do such a thing, and makes code far less readable/maintainable. And yes, it adds considerably to the overhead. minor in single-usage situations, but adds up quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a simple line of code `$result += $result * $i;` suffices in this context. The function `multiply` is redundant unless if some scalability was foreseen then in that case I would have written the code this way:

```
<?php
class Test{
    private $result;
    function __construct() {
        // our construct does what it do best: initialize $result
    }

    function multiply() {
        for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
            $this->result += $this->result * $i;
        }
        return $this->result;
    }
    // by moving the for loop inside multiply
    // our code becomes more concise, modular and it encourages high cohesion 
}
```

**NB:** The rule of thumb you should remember when making design decisions is that you should never let performance influence your coding style unless your code proves to be slow to an extent that compromise a reasonable responsiveness acceptable to the user.

Comment: Well I randomly found out the follwing code: http://pastebin.com/XjmcfHsK do you think the multiply method is not needed?

Comment: It's redundant too. It was better to move the multiplication inside  `calculate` that way the code becomes more concise.

Answer (score 1):

Normally when you find yourself repeating the same code over and over throughout your application, that's when you need to move it to its own function.
Especially if you're using it across several different classes.

You could try putting all of your common functions into some type of Functions class and instantiating it when it loads:

```
<?php

class Functions {

      public function multiply($num1, $num2) {

        return ($num1 * $num2);
      }

}

$helper = new Functions();

?>
```

Then, as long as you require_once that functions class on each page, you can call it from anywhere in your application by just saying

```
$helper->multiply($arg1, $arg2);
```